# Fullscreen enabled in Ubuntu Virtualbox VM without Guest Additions

Tags: virtualbox, dpkg, virtualization, fullscreen, guest-additions

Trying to delve into web application hacking, I installed a dedicated *Virtual Lab* set up by the academic [SEED project](https://seedsecuritylabs.org/). The [pre-built VM](https://seedsecuritylabs.org/lab_env.html) (based on *Ubuntu 16.04*) was already configured with everything needed for the requirements of the challenges.

As the VM *fullscreen* mode was activated, I expected the **guest-additions**/**dkms** packages to be installed, but that didn't seem to be the case : neither `dpkg -l guest` nor `dpkg -s virtualbox-guest-utils` nor even `dpkg -s virtualbox-guest-dkms` command was actually able to locate said packages.

So just out of curiosity, did I look at the wrong spots, or did they use another technique to get the fullscreen mode without the **guest additions** drivers ?

***NB.***: I've of course tried other commands to try to locate the packages, as `dpkg -l | grep guest`, but with no more success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guest additions can also be installed via a .run that dpkg does not know. Do a `ls /sbin/*vbox*` to look up the binary.

Comment: Indeed ! You really hit the nail on the head, Sir. Any online example of such a .run script, or how they get implemented ?

Comment: It's simply a executable or a shell script.

Comment: .run is only a extension that shows it can be run.